# залил клиентскую и серверную часть на хостинг render https://dashboard.render.com/ не взаимодействуют client и server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, render

серверная часть залита на веб-сервис, реакт клиентская часть залита на статик сайт.
Использую mongoDB в нем указывается ip в whitelist для подключения с сайта к клстеру.
Когда подключался локально добавил свой IP все работало, решил залить на хост ради того чтобы просто нацчиться как это делать, добавил сайт в чекер ip, добавил ip в whitelist. Запускаю сервер и клиент но на клиенте не выводит с БД данные вот что в логах ошибки:

```
==> Running 'node index.js'
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at Connection.openUri (/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:825:32)
    at /opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:414:10
    at /opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1290:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:413:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/api/index.js:18:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-1wkw4bv-shard-00-01.sknl5oe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-1wkw4bv-shard-00-02.sknl5oe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-1wkw4bv-shard-00-00.sknl5oe.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-9p70t4-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
==> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Running 'node index.js'
==> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:188
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^
MongooseError: Operation `restaurants.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/render/project/src/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:188:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
```

Node.js v20.11.1
==> Running 'node index.js'

Comment: Логи текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: сейчас сделаю секунду @void